# use the awk to generate a report from a file

Tags: linux, unix, awk

there is a file called list.lst which I wrote down its content. I need to write an awk script which generates a report with the name, department name and salary of all the directors in the file list.lst.

The script can be executed as:   awk –f director.awk list.lst

===========================================================

Create an awk script called marketing.awk which displays the name, the position and the salaries of all the employees in the marketing department.
The script can be executed as:
     ./marketing.awk list.lst

```
22233:charles harris     :g.m.    :sales         :12/12/52: 90000.00

29876:bill johnson      :director:production    :03/12/50:130000.00

25678:robert dylan      :d.g.m   :marketing     :04/19/43: 85000.00

22365:john woodcock     :director:personnel     :05/11/47:127000.00

25423:barry wood        :chairman:admin         :08/30/56:160000.00

21006:gordon lightfoot  :director:sales         :09/03/38:140000.00

26213:michael lennon    :g.m.    :accounts      :06/05/62:105000.00

24290:neil o'bryan      :executive:production   :09/07/50: 65000.00

22476:jackie woodhouse  :manager :sales         :05/01/59:110000.00

21265:p.j. wodehouse    :manager :accounts      :02/03/55: 97000.00

26521:derryk o'brien    :d.g.m   :accounts      :12/12/55: 85000.00

22312:bill wilcocks     :director:marketing     :09/26/45:125000.00

23564:ronie trueman     :executive:personnel    :07/06/47: 75000.00

22345:james wilcox      :g.m.    :marketing     :03/12/45:110000.00

20110:julie truman      :g.m.    :marketing     :12/31/40: 95000.00

20117:john trucman      :g.m.    :accounts      :12/25/41:110000.00

20123:frank -adams      :g.m.    :accounts      :09/25/48:110000.00

20129:Robin love        :director:sales         :10/01/08:120000.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

marketing.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
if($4~/marketing/)
{
print $2,$3,$6;
}
}
```

Comment: The shebang must include `-f`:  `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`.  Since it is common to prefer `/usr/bin/env` and that prevents the use of `-f`, it is more common to use `#!/bin/sh` and invoke awk directly.

Comment: is it ok to write for the first part:
 
if($3~/director/)
{
print $2,$4,$6;
}

Comment: Yes its ok.it will fetch you all the results from director department.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F: '$4 ~ /marketing/ {print $2, $3, $6}' list.lst
```